# Create WMPLib.IWMPFolderMonitorServices object

Tags: c#, wmplib

I try to create an object of `WMPLib.IWMPFolderMonitorServices` in C# to manage folders contain music. MSDN say

> "Retrieve a pointer to IWMPFolderMonitorServices by calling
>   QueryInterface through IWMPPlayer. and Retrieve a pointer to an
>   IWMPPlayer interface by calling the COM CoCreateInstance method. "

But I don't know how to do it. Please guide me. Thank a lot

Comment: In C# you do this with a cast.  The interface is very tricky however, it is only available if you enable remoting.  That's hard to do in C# as this requires implementing a COM object that implements IServiceProvider.  The documentation falls short on showing how to marry the two.

Comment: So, is there no way to do it in C# ?